# Powershell XML manipulation: Keep only nodes where date is max

Tags: xml, powershell, data-manipulation

I have an XML file with the following (simplified) structure:

```
<XML>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-11-01" />
       <Value value="123" />
    </Observation>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-11-02" />
       <Value value="456" />
    </Observation>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-12-01" />
       <Value value="789" />
    </Observation>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-12-02" />
       <Value value="222" />
    </Observation>
</XML>
```

The task at hand is to delete nodes where the date in the `value` attribute of the `Dimension` node *not* the maximum date. Or in other words: Only the nodes containing the maximum/highest date in the `value` attribute of the `Dimension` node should be kept. This should be done *per month*.

Hence, the result should look as follows:

```
<XML>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-11-02" />
       <Value value="456" />
    </Observation>
    <Observation>
       <Dimension value="2018-12-02" />
       <Value value="222" />
    </Observation>
</XML>
```

How can this be done in Powershell? I know how to read an XML file and how to make XPath-based queries:

```
$doc.SelectNodes("//Observation", $ns)
```

However, I do not know how to a) determine the maximum/highest date per month, and b) how to delete nodes that do not contain the maximum/highest date.

**EDIT:**

Another, maybe easier, way of doing this would be as follows:

1. find the highest/maximium dates per month
2. only keep nodes that
   have this date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by month using `Group-Object` simplifies the process.

```
$doc.XML.Observation | Group-Object { $_.Dimension.value.Substring(0,7) } | foreach {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.Dimension.value } -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | foreach { $doc.XML.RemoveChild($_) }
}
```

The following is the method corresponding to the case where there are multiple parent nodes.

```
$doc.SelectNodes("//message:DataSet/generic:Series", $ns) | foreach {
    $_.SelectNodes("./generic:Obs", $ns) | Group-Object { $_.ObsDimension.value.Substring(0,7) } | foreach {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.ObsDimension.value } -Descending |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | foreach { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a great answer. I just need some help to finally get it to work. Since the data in my sample is simplified (no namespaces), I actually access the nodes not via the "dot notation". Hence, the last command in your solution `$doc.XML.RemoveChild($_)` gives me trouble.

Comment: My actual command looks like this: `$doc.SelectNodes("//message:DataSet/generic:Series/generic:Obs", $ns) | Group-Object { $_.ObsDimension.value.Substring(0,7) } | foreach {$_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.ObsDimension.value } -Descending |
 Select-Object -Skip 1 | foreach { $doc.SelectNodes("//message:DataSet/generic:Series/generic:Obs", $ns).RemoveChild($_) } }`. It gives me the following exception: Exception calling "RemoveChild" with "1" argument(s): "The node to be removed is not a child of this node.". Can you help?

Comment: Because `generic: Obs` is a child node of `generic: Series`, the node that calls `RemoveChild` must be `generic: Series`. Also, it is better to use "SelectSingleNode" if there is only one target "generic: Series" node.

Comment: So, the last foreach is as follows.    `foreach { $doc.SelectSingleNode("//message:DataSet/generic:Series", $ns).RemoveChild($_) }`

Comment: The thing is, there are multiple `generic:Series` nodes, which brings me to another question, because the `Group` statement needs to be adapted. I need to group by each `generic:Series`, too. Should I create a separate question for that? thanks for your help

Comment: I adapted the suggestion from your last comment to `foreach { $doc.SelectNodes("//message:DataSet/generic:Series", $ns).RemoveChild($_) }`, because I have multiple `generic:Series` nodes. Then I get this error: `Exception calling "RemoveChild" with "1" argument(s): "The node to be removed is not a child of this node."`. I think my groupin also needs to be changed to reflect the fact that I have multiple `generic:Series` nodes.

Comment: one final thing: when I save the manipulated xml, the resulting file contains many empty lines. I assume these represent the deleted nodes. how can the empty lines be removed? i created a separate question for that. maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402196/powershell-remove-nodes-from-xml-and-remove-empty-lines-when-saving

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem when I delete childnodes, so I can not tell the cause. But there is a way to delete blank lines as text.　`$doc.OuterXml -split "\r\n" -notmatch "^\s*$" | out-file "your xml path" -encoding utf8`

Comment: i also tried to remove the new lines with regex, but (for some strange reason) it didn't work. i tried your code and the resulting file still looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/9HWEjcD

Comment: got it to work now with this: `$xml.OuterXml -replace "(?m)^`n", ""`. does this look fine to you or does it have any flaws?

Comment: I think its ok.

Comment: The cause of this problem is that the "PreserveWhitespace" property of XMLDocument is true. The output of `Invoke-RestMethod` seems to set the "PreserveWhitespace" property to ture by default.

Comment: ah great. thanks for the reply. is it possible to set `PreserveWhitespace` to `false` for `Invoke-RestMethod`?.

Answer (score 0):

This should do excatly what you want:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

$filePath   = "inputfile.xml"
$filePath1  = "outputfile.xml"

$xmlContent = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlContent.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xmlContent = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filePath))

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$highestValues = @()

$oldMonth = ""
$oldYear  = ""

$xmlContent.XML.Observation.Dimension | Sort-Object { $_.value }  -Descending | ForEach-Object {

    $currentDate  = $_.value
    $currentYear  = $currentDate.Substring(0,4)
    $currentMonth = $currentDate.Substring(5,2)

    if( $currentYear -ne $oldYear -or $currentMonth -ne $oldMonth ) {
        $oldYear  = $currentYear
        $oldMonth = $currentMonth
        $highestValues.Add( $currentDate )
    }
}

$numItems   = ($xmlContent.XML.Observation.Dimension).Count

for( $i = $numItems - 1; $i -ge 0; $i-- ) {

    if( !$highestValues.Contains( $xmlContent.XML.Observation.Dimension[$i].value ) ) {
        [void]$xmlContent.XML.RemoveChild( $xmlContent.XML.Observation[$i] )
    }

}

[void]$xmlContent.Save( $filePath1 )
```