# Powershell remove nodes from XML and remove empty lines when saving

Tags: xml, powershell, removechild

Via an Rest-API call I receive an XML file in Powershell.

```
#calling the REST service and get XML result
$xml = try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ErrorAction Stop   
} catch {
    LogWrite "An exception was caught: $($formatstring -f $fields)";
    exit;
}
```

I then remove nodes by using `removeChild()`.

```
#manipulate XML
$xml.SelectNodes("//XPathQuery").ParentNode.RemoveChild(...)
```

Finally I save the manipulated XML.

```
#save XML
$xml.Save("$targetDirectory\$filename");
```

The resulting XML-file has multiple empty lines.

[image]

I assume that each removed note resulted in one additional empty line. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that the `PreserveWhitespace` property of `XmlDocument` is true.
 The output of `Invoke-RestMethod` seems to set the `PreserveWhitespace` property to ture by default.

But setting `$doc.PreserveWhitespace = $false` to the output of `Invoke-RestMethod` does not solve the problem because line feed codes remain.

I can not find the option to unset `PreserveWhitespace` in `Invoke-RestMethod`, so I think converting the response to `XmlDocument` by yourself is the easiest solution.

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.LoadXml((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url).Content)
```

Answer (score -1):

I normally use xml databases to handle small multi attribute databases and had this error I used a linq statement and had to use from, where, and select to select just the elements I wanted to delete.

```
var elementsToSelect = from ele in xmlDoc.Elements("List").Elements("Entry")
                       where ele != null && ele.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
                        select ele;
```

I would have to see the query to  see if you are selecting a board range of nodes or just a single one like I did above that solved my error. I was one level off and it selected all the nodes and removed them.